# sources list-synaptic package manager

Tags: ubuntu, debian, installation, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I am having some trouble and i need a kind/patient individual to assist me. I am new to the world of computers. When i got the computer i had trouble installing bitmessage so a friend suggested i alter the /etc/apt/sources.list. It worked and all was well (i was able to install and use bitmessage via terminal). So i tried to install openshot video editor via the synaptic package manager and that went great until i try to use it and nothing will happen(more on this later).So in my wisdom i assumed because the updates version was removed from the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.that maybe i should edit it to the original state(i saved it before altering as my friend suggested). So i opened the `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. and copy/pasted it to the original text put in by the installer. After doing so i can no longer access the synaptic package manager and am getting the following message:

```
E:malformed line 5 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list (URI)
E:the list of sources could not be read.
go to the repositiory dialog to correct the problem
E_cache->open()failed,please report
```

I have attached the original `/etc/apt/sources.list` text by the installer and also the one my friend made for me. The openshot is installed but simply does nothing. I am not sure if i have saved the sources.list correctly or for that matter what is going on.

Thank you for your time, wisdom, and patience.

Original `sources.list` :

[image]

Comment: 1) it's better to copy/paste content of a file as text, not as graphic. in your case there is an issue on line `deb cdrom:[Debian...`. but this line did not fit on the screen, so we can't see it all. 2) since you are new to computers, i would suggest more user friendly editor, ie `gedit`. 3) everything after a `#` sign is a comment. 4) can you please comment out 5th line `deb cdrom:[Debian...` by putting `#` at the begining of a line, and try again with synaptic? this line refers to cdrom, and i don't think you use it after installation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 th line is:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie ...
```

You should comment the cdrom source and add the `main` repo to your `sources.list`

There is an example to the `sources.list` (It will work for you. You can also choose the nearest mirror):

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie ...

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

Save your `sources.list` then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The error should be disappear when you run synaptic.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hashed out the cd rom line and then added your sources list text. works like a charm.